# Why printf doesn't print directly a variable in C?

Tags: c, printf

So the question properly is, supose I have this code here:

```
char characteres[]="Hello";
printf(characteres);
```

This will print Hello, but if a do:

```
char character='k';
printf(character);
```

This wont print anything, why?

Comment: Read the *documentation*. What does the *documentation* say about the first parameter? Why would using a character (being from a variable is not relevant) be expected to *not* work?

Comment: I didnt understood well the first parameter, it says must be a const char, but even declared with a const char nothing happened

Comment: Read it again: “char” and “char *” (a char[] decays to a char pointer) are different types. There are addition restrictions, as in it must also be a valid string with special interpretation. Read the documentation and see the examples. Also, enable compiler warnings..

Comment: Also, passing a variable as the first argument to `printf` is dangerous. If the string happens to contain a `%` character it will be interpreted as a format specifier.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

`printf` asks for a string (null-terminated '\0') which as variable is a pointer to char (char*).

The second case is just a char variable. What you could do is

```
char character='k';
printf(&character);
```

but you will see some garbage behind your letter, because printf asks for a null-terminated string.

So passing a char to printf directly is not a good idea. Better do this:

```
char character='k';
printf("%c", character);
```

And the argument passed to printf and the function will create the null-terminated string for you.

Answer (score -2):

Please enable all warnings with your compiler. If using [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (all warnings and debug info). Read the wikipaedia page on the [C programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)).

Then you'll get warnings. Take them into account and improve your code to get none. Read also [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

> This wont print anything, why?

Probably because `stdout` is usually line buffered. See [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setvbuf.3.html). Read more [about `<stdio.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io).   You should call [fflush](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush).

> ```
> char character='k';
> printf(character);
> ```

**This should not even compile** (except on old or buggy compilers). It is [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) (you pass a `char` as the first argument to [`printf` documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) to take a `const char*`)

Please read a good book on C programming, such as [*Modern C*](http://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Then take time to read the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Consider using tools like the [Clang static analyzer](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/).

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The real problem here is that the OP is passing a `char` to a [function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) that takes `const char *`. `stdout` line buffering is not the correct answer here (though is a useful note).

Comment: I just improved my answer

Comment: I'm still not convinced the edited answer is accurate. The reason why it won't print anything hasn't got anything to do with `stdout` line buffering.

Comment: The code should not compile against a C99 compiler. If it does compile the compiler is wrong or obsolete (C89 did allow that)

Comment: I wasn't referring to that part of your answer. I was referring to the part where you mention that the problem is "probably because stdout is usually line buffered". As mentioned before, this isn't relevant to the OP's problem.